# Facebook Graph api get Posts starting from x post (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i've serched a lot without find an answer to this.
is possible to retrieve Fb posts of a certain public page starting from a post id?(for example tomorrow start collecting posts from the last post of today)
Let's take for example Bill Gates page

the idea would be to do something similar to:

```
$id = 216311481960; //Bill's fb id
$last_post = 10153219939326961 // last bill posts   
try {
        $request= $id.'/posts?since='.$last_post.'&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx';
        $search = $fb->get($request);
        if (isset($search)){
            //do something
            }
    }           
catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage()."<h1>".$id."</h1>";
}
```

obviously since parameter has to be a date and that code wont work.
Any Idea?
Thanks in advance.
**Edit**

i try to search for all posts of a specific Facebook user starting not at a certain date but from a certain post, lets say that today i grab users postid1,postid2,postid3 (postid3 is the last post i've taken, and i save that id) next time i would to grab new posts published after postid3 (since postid3)

Comment: This is a good example, please edit your post and add it, after adding it, delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the url, I just made it work recently. This is from a python code, but the URL should work the same way.

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=" + ids[:-1] +
    "&fields=name,posts.limit(5).since(10+days+ago)" +
    "{from,to,full_picture,message,caption,description," +
    "link,name,shares,likes.summary(true)," +
    "comments.summary(true),created_time,is_hidden," +
    "message_tags,place,type,with_tags}")
```

This will get the last 5 posts from the last 10 days for several page ids. It will also get the total number of likes and comments as summary.

It took me a while to dig this info from the net, I found that since= has changed to since().

I tried to retrieve some reference where it's documented, so far with no success. I'll give you an update if I find it.

Comment: Thanks but i dont need posts of last 10 days, but as i said to @tr-catch-finally :i try to search for all posts of a specific Facebook user starting not at a certain date but from a certain post, lets say that today i grab users postid1,postid2,postid3 (postid3 is the last post i've taken, and i save that id) next time i would to grab new posts published after postid3

Comment: Well, the tools in this Url may help you achieve what you said. "for example tomorrow start collecting posts from the last post of today". you can get the posts from the last 24 hours like this. So every day you have fresh posts for the day. Since() works with time only, I'm not aware of a mechanism like this for ids.

Comment: That's true but this script will run as cronjob, and i'm scared of getting duplicates. if conjob starts at 6.00 and i start grabbing posts since 'yesterday' i will grab posts from 00.00 of the day before  until 05.59 of today , tomorrow i will have duplicates of all posts published from 00 to 06 of today(6 hours).

Comment: I fetch posts with a cron job, too using the above URL and save them into a db. I check if the post with the given Facebook post id exists. You can decide to ignore such ids and not save them again. I overwrite them, because like and comment counts may increase. So I avoid duplicates.